# Android implementing static or nonstatic fragment interfaces

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Suppose I have this fragment:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    public interface CallerProxy {
        public void publishParams(Object... dataParams);
    }

    private CallerProxy mCallerProxy;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof CallerProxy) {
            this.mCallerProxy = (CallerProxy) activity;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        this.mCallerProxy = null;
    }

    protected void sendCustomMessage(Object... objects) {
        if (mCallerProxy != null) {
            mCallerProxy.publishParams(objects);
        }
    }

}
```

What is the difference of having the interface defined static or non-static? Even if I declare `CallerProxy` static or not then in the parent activity I will have this:

```
public class MyProxyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements CallerProxy {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(...) and other relevant code
    }

    @Override
    public void publishParams(Object... dataParams) {
        // /
    }
}
```

From what I know, if the interface is declared as static, then the interface is tied to `FragmentA` class object and if I don't declare it static then it will be tied to `FragmentA` instance object - will this lead to memory leaks? 
What problems may appear if the interface is not static and why?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3

Comment: @Luksprog: multzam, will look into it ...

Comment: @Luksprog: taken from that link: `Member interfaces are implicitly static so they are never considered to be inner classes`. Please add an answer so I will accept it. So having static or non-static interface in the class declaration is the same thing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `interface` defined as a class member is already declared(implicitly) as `static` so there isn't any diference between the two scenarios you mentioned. Also, as a reference, a quote from the [Java language specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

*`Member interfaces (§8.5) are implicitly static so they are never considered to be inner classes.`*